# my table size changes with content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a 2 by 4 table in HTML with in every td a div. like this:

```
<table id="buildingtable">
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    `<td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                    <td><div class="building">
                        test
                    </div><td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The idea is to put a image and a littlebit of text in every div
The table looks fine with only text, but as soon as I place an image inside the div it changes the size of every first td in every tr. And it changes only the first (so the first vertical row) wich is strange. This is the css I used for the table and the divs:

```
#buildingtable{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 1.8%;
margin-top: -1.5%;
}

.building{
    display:block;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    width:80%;
    max-width:80%;
    padding: 5% 7.5%;
    background: #aba000;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 8px #001db0;
    border-style: groove ridge ridge groove;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output..?

Comment: Is there any particular reason your `<td>`'s aren't closed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a simple fix, you've placed your divisions in the wrong place.

Instead of:

```
<td><div class="building">
                    test
                </div><td>
```

Why don't you try:

```
<div class="building"><td>
                    test
                <td></div>
```

You need the table to be adjusted to that width and not the text.

Comment: Actually I need it to have every division to be in a single td, because they need to be seperated from each other, so I get a 2X4 table with 8 boxes. Also it shouldn't asjust to the content at all, it should stay the size it is and I will make the content fit. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Thank you anyway for your quick reaction

Answer (score 0):

For `height` you should rather use `100%` in `.building` to have all `td` of the same height. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jv2M/). Though, I don't know exactly what it should look like in the end.

Comment: |---------|  |---------|
|         |  |         |
|---------|  |---------|

|---------|  |---------|
|         |  |         |
|---------|  |---------|

|---------|  |---------|
|         |  |         |
|---------|  |---------|

|---------|  |---------|
|         |  |         |
|---------|  |---------|

I hope this drawing makes sense. every box should contain a picture and some text. damn the drawing failed... it's 2 boxes next to each other with underneath them 3 more boxes so you get a 2 boxes width and 4 boxes high